# icheck set dynamically checked for checkbox or radio button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, icheck

I can check which button clicked or not given below:

But what I need to do is by ajax call back if I get value 'Y' or 'N' then set checked for radio button. please help me through this.

```js
$('input').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
  radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
$('input[type=radio][name=kitchen]').on('ifChecked', function() {
  if (this.value === "N") {
    alert('No');
  } else {
    alert('Yes');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>Is Kitchen <input type="radio" name="kitchen" value="Y" class="flat"> 
     Yes <input type="radio" name="kitchen" value="N" class="flat"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note how I created a [mcve] for you. Now please change it to reflect your exact issue. It looks to me you just need to change your alert with $.get(...) or $.post(....) and do something with the return. The [iCheck documentation](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) - look at methods will show how not to check until you have tested the value

Comment: from server end if i get value 'Y' or 'N' by ajax callback. i need to set checked according to value for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your ajax call, then in the callback check the returned data and use `iCheck()` function to check the desired element.

**Example :**

```
$.get('url', {}, function( data ){
    if ( data === "Y" ){
        $(':radio[name=kitchen][value=Y]').iCheck('check');
    } else {
        $(':radio[name=kitchen][value=N]').iCheck('check');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('input').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
  radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});

var data = "N";

if ( data === "Y" ){
    $(':radio[name=kitchen][value=Y]').iCheck('check');
} else {
    $(':radio[name=kitchen][value=N]').iCheck('check');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>Is Kitchen <input type="radio" name="kitchen" value="Y" class="flat"> 
     Yes <input type="radio" name="kitchen" value="N" class="flat"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx for your reply i have already done that but problem is in selector.would u please get me through this. will it be like$('input[type=radio][name=kitchen]').iCheck('check'); for 'Y'

Comment: `$(':radio[name=kitchen][value='+data+']').iCheck('check');`